# Quote class preference is not working

Tags: magento2.4.4

I want to overwrite validateMinimumAmount function that is available in Magento\Quote\Model\Quote class.

Below is my di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote" type="Myname\Minamount\Model\Quote" />
</config>
```

below is my preference class:

```
namespace Myname\Minamount\Model;

class Quote extends Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
{

    public function validateMinimumAmount($multishipping = false)
    {
      // here my logic is going 
    }
}
```

At the time of di compile it is showing below error:

> Class 'Myname\Minamount\Model\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote' not found#

Magento version : 2.4.3-p1

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sanjeev the code you share in this question is not clear can you please check and intimate again ? Because cannot see the namespace of the PHP file and di.xml file code is also missing.

Comment: Can you attach the di.xml code again?
I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Your preference class need to like this.

```
namespace Myname\Minamount\Model;

class Quote extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
{

    public function validateMinimumAmount($multishipping = false)
    {
      // here my logic is going 
    }
}
```

Then run all magento commands and then check.